# input box does not appear in tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue with tkinter. Basically When I attempt to create an input box, the window opens with the title only.

```
 from tkinter import *
 window = Tk()
 window.title("name generator")

 def openInterface():
  inputLabel = Label(window, text="Enter your name")
  inputLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
  print(inputLabel)
```

Am i missing something? My apologies in advance for this is a noob question.

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call your `openInterface` function. Functions are different from code in the global scope becasue they only get executed when called, not when they are defined.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("name generator")
openInterface()

def openInterface():
    inputLabel = Label(window, text="Enter your name")
    inputLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)
    print(inputLabel)
```

Comment: hey @chuck2002 Thanks for your response and the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing two things, you haven't call 
funtion and also you you need to use

```
window.mainloop()
```